# creating histogram bins in r

Tags: r, histogram

I have this code.

```
a = c("a", 1)
b = c("b",2)
c = c('c',3)
d = c('d',4)
e = c('e',5)
z = data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
hist = hist(as.numeric(z[2,]))
```

I am trying to have a histogram such that the bins would be `a,b,c,d,e`

and the freq values would be `1,2,3,4,5`.

However, it gives me an empty screen(no bins at all for histogram model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are plotting the factor levels of each column for row 2, which is in this case always 1.

When creating the dataframe you add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to avoid converting the numbers to factors. This should work:

```
z = data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
hist(as.numeric(z[2,]))
```

Comment: Can you explain the factors thing. I don't really understand it even after googling

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this would work for you: it creates a data frame with the *x* elements being the letters *a* through 'e', and the *y* elements being the numbers 1 through 5. It then renders a histogram and tells ggplot not to perform any binning.

```
library(ggplot2)
tmp <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5], y = 1:5)
ggplot(tmp, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_histogram(stat = "identity")
```